# How to use the parameter to update the value of a variable in another class? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, parameters

Im trying to update the variable Total in another class by trying to get the subtotal from an Order. Then that value will go inside a method in OrderTest.cs that will add on to the value Total from the other class. What am I doing wrong. CS1061: 'Order does not contain a definition for subtotal.(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

My Class Order.cs____________________

```
class Order {

    
    private static decimal total;
    public static decimal Total { get { return total; } set { total = value; } }
    public static string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public static int OrderNum { get; set; }
    public static decimal SubTotal { get; set; }

    public Order (string customername, int ordernum, decimal subtotal, string Item1, string Item2, string Item3, string Item4)
    {
        
        CustomerName = customername;
        OrderNum = ordernum;
        SubTotal = subtotal;
        item1 = Item1;
        item2 = Item2;
        item3 = Item3;
        item4 = Item4;
    }
```

Then this is the OrderTest.cs ___________________________

```
//This method updates the total from the class

    public static void UpdateTotal(decimal UpValue)
    {
        Order.Total += UpValue;
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declaration of variables 
        char selection;
        int orderEdit;
        int oNum;
        bool endMenue = false;

        //string customername, int ordernum, decimal subtotal, string Item1, string Item2, string Item3, string Item4

        Order order1 = new Order("Fred_Flintsone", 123, 56.75M, "Beef", "Rice", "Bread", "Milk" );
        Order.Total = UpdateTotal(order1.subtotal); //This is where I am having issues trying to get subtotal
        //I want to use the subtotal to update the Total in the Order.cs, using the method called UpdateTotal }
```

Comment: Seems likely you want `order1.Total`, not `Order.Total`, and `order1.SubTotal` instead of `order1.subtotal`. It's also not clear why you have the `UpdateTotal()` method at all...what's the point of that? I find this question neither clear nor useful; it seems most likely that the main issue is a simple typographical error and no answer to this question is likely to help any other user in the future.

Comment: Also in addition to @PeterDuniho comment - read about [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) modifier.

Comment: Notice: The type of "UpdateTotal's return value" is void, and you cannot convert it to decimal. Static properties can only be accessed by class name. If you want to get a specific property of an instance , you need to declare a non-static property `public decimal subtotal { get; set; }`.